# jQuery + Ubiquity: Return a document object from a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ubiquity

I'm trying to write a simple [Ubiquity](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Labs/Ubiquity) command that will run a query on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), and display the results in the Ubiquity preview object.

I need to set the `innerHTML` of the preview object.  I am currently doing this to get the HTML, which is only a start:

```
//...
jQuery.get( 'http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=' + input.text, 
    null, 
    function( page ) {
        previewBlock.innerHTML = page;
    }
);
```

I have 2 problems/questions:

1. Wolfram takes 5-10 sec to generate all the HTML on the page, so the `get()` command returns incomplete HTML
   **How can it wait for the page to load completely?**
2. The results have `id="results"` on the Wolfram page, I'd like to just get the results by doing something like this: 
   `previewBlock.innerHTML = page.getElementById('results').innerHTML`
   **How can this be done with the URL I'm using?**

Another option might be to create a new element using the Wolfram URL as source and append it to `previewBlock` -- I'm not sure how to do that though.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here is the Ubiquity script I'm using -- It will fetch the images from the source HTML and output them in a loop. Note: `CmdUtils.previewGet(pblock, opt)` calls `jQuery.get(opt)`

```
CmdUtils.CreateCommand({
  name: "wolfram",
  takes: {"input": noun_arb_text},
  icon: "http://www.wolframalpha.com/favicon.ico",
  homepage: "http://www.wolframalpha.com",
  author: {name:"Jason Coon"},
  description: "Searches Wolfram Alpha and loads results in to Preview pane.",

  preview: function(pblock, input) {
    CmdUtils.previewGet(pblock,
      'http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=' + input.text,
      null,
      function(data){
        var resultStart = data.indexOf("results",0);
        var beginPos = data.indexOf("<img src", resultStart);
        var endPos = 0;
        var html = ""
        while(beginPos != -1){
          endPos = data.indexOf(">", beginPos);
          html = html + "<br><br>" + data.substring(beginPos, endPos);
          beginPos = data.indexOf("<img src", endPos);
        }
        pblock.innerHTML = html;
      }
    );
  }
})
```

Comment: First of all, how are you getting past the "restricted URI denied" error?

Comment: Ubiquity seems to take care of it, and is able to fetch the data.

Comment: Please post the code that includes the ubiquity call?

Comment: I added the code to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is even possible using the **Ubiquity Preview**. The problem is that when sending the request to Wolfram, the page finishes loading very quickly, but it continues to fetch additional information asynchronously as you already know.

If this was done through a browser window instead of the Ubiquity preview, you could actually load the page into a hidden iframe and check the contents before updating the results div. However, this option is not available in current version of Ubiquity.

Here's a screenshot of running your command and passing the text "USA GDP". Two divs get display information and 2 more start fetching additional data asynchronously as soon as the page is finished loading.
[alt text http://exterbase.com/wolfram-result.png](http://exterbase.com/wolfram-result.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think your idea is doable, but I think you'll have more success with an AJAX call to the Wolfram|Alpha API than by trying to parse a response to the W-A web front-end. For documentation on the WolframAlpha API, see here: www.wolframalpha.com/WolframAlphaAPI.pdf

I think changing your approach to interact with the API should solve your problems. If you want to continue pursuing your current approach, you might want to examine the code for the built-in Wikipedia command to see how they parse the search results and then asynchronously retrieve article summaries for the preview.